# Players power-up not dissapearing after being collected

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a simple asteroid style, top down shooter. In the game there is a power-up which allows the players character to be invincible to enemy fire for a short time.

After a while the power-ups effect should slowly fade away, however this is not the case. Once the power-up has been collected it doesn't fade away, making the player invincible.

I have two classes which are involved with the shield (power-up).

**Game.as** : in the Game function there is a line saying that the shield should not be visible when the game starts (ship.shield.visible = false;)

The same line is in my gameOver function which states that when the game is over, the shield should not appear.

**PowerUp.as** : Here is the code for the entire PowerUp.as

package{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class PowerUp extends MovieClip{

    var speed:Number;
    var type:Number;

    function PowerUp(){

        speed = 2;
        type = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
        this.x = 650;
        this.y = Math.random()*200+50;
        addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);

    }

    function enterFrame(e:Event){

        this.rotation -= 2;
        this.x -= speed;

        if(this.hitTestObject(Game.ship)){

            if(type == 1){
                Game.ship.takeDamage(Game.ship.health - Game.ship.maxHealth);
            }
            if(type == 2){
                for(var i in EnemyShip.list){
                    EnemyShip.list[i].takeDamage(1);
                }
            }
            if(type == 3){
                Game.ship.shield.visible = true;
                Game.ship.shield.alpha -= 0.05;
            if(Game.ship.shield.alpha == 0){
                Game.ship.shield.visible = false;
                Game.ship.shield.alpha = 1;
            }

            removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);

        }

        if(this.x < -30){

            removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Given you are trying to program a timered effect, you should add a counter for "ship" enterframe listener. Give it an "invulnerability" counter that will be filled with a powerup (type==3 one) with a certain value of your choice. Then, in `takeDamage` function you check if that damage is positive (you use negative damage for healing - ok IMHO) AND invulnerability counter is greater than 0, then no damage is taken. And each frame decrement that counter, once 0, hide the shield so that your ship is vulnerable again.

```
if(type == 3){
            Game.ship.shield.visible = true;
            Game.ship.shield.alpha = 1;
            Game.ship.invulnerability=50;
        }
```

And into the listener for ship you stuff:

```
if (invulnerability>0) {
    invulnerability--;
    if (invulnerability==0) {
       shield.visible=false;
    } else if (invulnerability<20) {
       shield.alpha=invulnerability*0.05; // fade out if close to end
    }
}
```

Don't forget to initialize `invulnerability` with 0 somewhere. Preferably declare it, it's required if `ship` is not directly a `MovieClip`, which can get properties at runtime.

Comment: You can also use the Timer-class to count how many seconds the shield has left.

Comment: @Joetjah I prefer to have a unified time source, either frames or timer(s), mainly because of a possible desynch due to bad programming etc, where 1 second starts to equal 5 frames or less, so anything timered goes useless in terms of gameplay, as it still progresses by frames.

Comment: Doesn't the use of Timer actually make sure the application is synched? If somehow your application runs with 5 frames per second, then your invulnerability would last 10 seconds.

Comment: @Joetjah Indeed, but within that 10 seconds you won't be able to do more than what you do within normal timespan of 50 frames. This is fair, while it does give the player more time to actively think inside the game. But in case a powerup would only last 2 seconds, and the game would lag to 5fps, the player would only have 10 frames of invulnerability, thus 10 chances to do an elementary move, which in most cases is not enough.

Comment: True, it depends on the game. If for example an enemy is moving towards you, you want to make sure it works equally. Also, when playing online (multiplayer?), you don't want to have it frame-based but time-based so all players are on the same thing.